# Processing and "OpenGL ES API with no current context"

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl-es, processing

Looking for OpenGL ES guru here !

I saw many "E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)" questions here but I'm still stuck just like 2 month ago.

If you start a brand new Android Processing project in Android Studio
like this: http://android.processing.org/tutorials/android_studio/index.html

you get this "call to OpenGL ES API with no current context" error when you "onResume" from "onPause"

Of course I am discussing this with the Processing makers
https://github.com/processing/processing-android/issues/413

But it looks like a dead end :(

Could it be something a Android/OpenGL boss could fix easily ?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

i dont know cause i havent used Processing but i can tell you that i have seen that error before. it happened when i tried to run code from a touch input event without wrapping it in a queueEvent. because apparently this is needed because opengl runs on a separate threads and this is how the threads can communicate safely.